# When connecting Galaxy SII to Eclipse LogCat begins to throw out errors like crazy

Tags: java, logcat

Hey was Hoping someone could help me out.  I just started to learn to develop for Android and LogCat is throwing me for a loop.  When I connect my Galaxy SII to the computer in USB debugging mode, Logcat starts to spray out errors like crazy.  I'm not sure why this is happening because its never happened before, even just last night when I was testing out some hello world-ish type apps.  Any idea what's happening?  The error messages are below:

```
01-15 13:52:59.999: E/AlarmManagerService(1971): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 712.099000000
01-15 13:53:00.009: E/AlarmManagerService(1971): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 632.522000000
01-15 13:53:00.559: E/DataRouter(1804): usb connection is true 
01-15 13:53:00.559: E/DataRouter(1804): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
01-15 13:53:02.558: E/DataRouter(1804): usb connection is true 
01-15 13:53:02.558: E/DataRouter(1804): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
01-15 13:53:04.564: E/DataRouter(1804): usb connection is true 
01-15 13:53:04.564: E/DataRouter(1804): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
01-15 13:53:06.563: E/DataRouter(1804): usb connection is true 
01-15 13:53:06.563: E/DataRouter(1804): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
01-15 13:53:08.563: E/DataRouter(1804): usb connection is true 
01-15 13:53:08.563: E/DataRouter(1804): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
01-15 13:53:10.563: E/DataRouter(1804): usb connection is true 
01-15 13:53:10.563: E/DataRouter(1804): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but I had a similar thing happen when I plugged in my Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 the other day after installing the driver, Kies. I had to reinstall it to make it work properly. http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads.